# How to select a value from column (B, C or D) based on the value in Column A, into a new column D in R

Tags: r, case, mutate

I have a large dataset in R with c. 20 variables and 1000s of observations. I'm new to R and can't find a way to select 1 value from multiple columns into a new column based on a
I want to create a new column (F) that selects a value from columns B:E based on the value returned in column A.

Is that possible?

I have tried to use this code:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("dplyr")

df <- df %>%
  mutate(F = case_when(A == 1 ~ B,
                       A == 2 ~ C,
                       A == 3 ~ D,
                       A == 4 ~ E,
                       TRUE ~ NA))
```

and received this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `F = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Calling a column or variable `F` is probably not a great idea, and may be where your error is coming from, because it can evaluate as  a shorthand for `FALSE`. You can see this with syntax highlighting--even in your post, "F" is highlighted the same as numbers and `TRUE`, whereas "A", "B", etc are not

Comment: Likely you need to replace `NA` with `NA_real_` or `NA_character_`, depending on the nature of `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong that has worked! thank you!